# In a-frame how can I stop all sounds when a new sound starts playing?

Tags: audio, aframe

When I play click on the a-entity it plays the sound, but how can I get it to stop all other sounds when played, so it is not a loud muddled mess of a thing?

I've googled the problem and tried adding the codes they use, but they haven't been working, I've tried about 5 different ones.

I am running my sound like this:

```
<audio id="mercury-sound" src="mercury.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>

<script id="mercury" type="text/html">
          <a-entity class="mercury"
            geometry="primitive: sphere; radius: 0.67"
            material="shader: flat; src: ${thumb}"
            event-set__mouseenter="_target: #image-mercury; material.src: ${src}; opacity: 1"
            event-set__mouseleave="_target: #image-mercury; material.src: ${src}; opacity: 0">
            </a-entity>
          </script>


<a-entity template="src: #mercury" sound="src: #mercury-sound; on"></a-entity>
```

I want it to play the sound and stop all other sounds when played.

EDIT: if anyone else is having this issue, this is what fixed it

> The template component is creating child nodes, You need to grab let el = e.target.parentNode. Check it out here also i would manage all sound-related logic in js, but thats another topic :) btw where is poor pluto ! – Piotr Adam Milewski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using `js`. The idea is to:

1) keep an array of the elements with sound
2) when one is clicked - iterate through the array and stop sounds
3) play the 'clicked' one

Having a setup like this:

```
<a-box sound='#first'></a-box>
<a-box sound='#second'></a-box>
<a-box sound='#third'></a-box>
```

You can create a script, which will:

```
// grab all elements with the sound component
var soundEls = document.querySelectorAll('[sound]')

// make sure all of those react on a 'click' event
for (var i = 0; i < soundEls.length; i++) {
   var item = soundEls[i];
   item.addEventListener('click', e => {
        let el = e.target

        // don't replay an already playing sound
        let isPlaying = el.components.sound.isPlaying

        // stop all sounds
        soundEls.forEach(soundEl => {
            soundEl.components.sound.stopSound()
        })

        // play the clicked sound if isn't already playing
        if (!isPlaying)
            el.components.sound.playSound()
  })
}
```

Usually, i'd recommend using an aframe [custom component](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html#sidebar). But it may be easier to get the idea this way. Check it out in [this glitch](https://glitch.com/~aframe-multiple-sounds).

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, it might be because my sounds are mouse overs, the cursor is the centre of the screen, so you have to look at it to play the sound, and when you look at the next object it should stop the first sound and play the second.


Is there a way to work this script with mouseenter? changing the 'click' to 'mouseenter' didn't do anything

Comment: Switched to mouseover with [mouse](https://jsfiddle.net/Lu85arq2/1/) and [<a-cursor>](https://jsfiddle.net/wkjrqLg7/1/). Both seem to be working. I've also added a little workaround for the audio not playing for the first time.

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot get this to work, could you take a look at it please, I don't know what part is wrong or why it isn't working. [link](https://glitch.com/~agate-azimuth)

Comment: The template component is creating child nodes, You need to grab `let el = e.target.parentNode`. Check it out [here](https://glitch.com/~stack-56093267) also i would manage all sound-related logic in `js`, but thats another topic :)
btw where is poor pluto !

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I thought if I put the js in the html in a <script> tag it would still work, apparently it doesn't and requires to be in the js file. But thank you. And Pluto declined my invite :(

Comment: i moved the script to be sure it executed after the page loads. It should work also if the `<script>` tags would be at the end of the body. If everything is working feel free to mark the anwser